# elasticsearch search like "distint count" in sql?

Tags: elasticsearch

I put the following data in elasticsearch.

```
POST movies/movie
{
    "title": "Apocalypse Now",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1979,
    "genres": ["Drama", "War", "Foo"]
}

POST movies/movie
{
    "title": "Apocalypse Now",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1979,
    "genres": ["Drama", "War", "Foo", "Bar"]
}

POST movies/movie
{
    "title": "Apocalypse Now",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1979,
    "genres": ["Drama", "Comic", "Bar"]
}
```

And I want to get the following results.

```
"Drama" : 3
"War" : 2
"Foo" : 2
"Bar" : 2
"Comic" : 1
```

How do I get these results?
Thank you for your help in solving this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), like this:

```
POST movies/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "genres.keyword",
        "size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```